# Is it possible to have a nodeJS program select options/fill out forms in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

this is my first post here so apologies in advance if I format anything incorrectly.

I'm working on a project for an internship and after a couple days of researching I can't figure out a solution to the next step in our project automating some reports.

**TLDR:** Is it possible for a javascript file executed via nodeJS to 1. select an option in a dropdown menu/list in an html page/website, and 2. enter text/data into a form on that html page/website. We want this to be able to run without human interaction, currently the idea is that a batch file scheduled to run at a specific time will open command prompt and run a .js file that will do these tasks

Our company has a web interface linked to a SQL database that so far has been used to manually enter data that is then updated in the database, and is the basis for several reports. We are working on having the process of pulling data from one database to the end of entering data in a separate database be fully automated on varying schedules. For now since data entered in the website will already automatically go into the second database, we are hoping (at least for now) to just have a nodeJS program that will open the web page with proper credentials (already got that working) and then select a specific option from a drop-down menu and then with that selected enter data into the form loaded from that selection.

The contents of the files I'm working with apart from the code I've got for testing are a bit long, so I've put them in a github repository for your reference linked below. The code I've written so far to test things out is found in TestJS2 and TestJSHttp https://github.com/crowbar1212/Internship-project

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do a DB migration/synchronization? If so using a webpage UI to do so doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. Would you not want to write a script that just directly calls the two DBs? Am I missunderstanding...

Comment: I haven't done any webscraping with Node.JS, I'm sure you can do it like that, but one other way to do this though would be to shoehorn a browser automation tool like Cypress to do so...

Comment: Also you should remove the */settings* from your github link it makes it 404.

Comment: `The contents of the files I'm working with apart from the code I've got for testing are a bit long, so I've put them in a github repository` code that only exists in a link to an external site should be ignored. The link can become invalid anytime making the question incomplete and due to that possibility useless for future readers. You have to create a [mcve].

Comment: You are looking for something puppeteer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered using my non-school email account:

Yes! as @t.niese commented, this is something that can relatively easily be done using puppeteer, check out the github page or https://pptr.dev/ for info on how to use puppeteer.